# Ideals in a Von-Neumann regular ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I want to show the following result directly:

> Let R be a regular ring then every ideal is the intersection of
> maximal ideals containing it.

I know that every ideal of a regular ring is a z-ideal (semiprime), which are intersection of prime ideals, but every prime ideal in a regular ring is maximal and thus the above result follows. See [G.Mason z-ideals and prime ideals](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869373900240/pdf?crasolve=1&r=7a4884b6edc8f43d&ts=1678251667040&rtype=https&vrr=UKN&redir=UKN&redir_fr=UKN&redir_arc=UKN&vhash=UKN&host=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&iv=234cce30369b748071c59540fe343a3b&token=64386336366135343138303062396361316537383331343036656261646332306562663264326539313532393234656165393938643162303635623434373238383135643a336464386339663262313965346630313534396530346664&text=9142fe35539cd3dbdf801d3c1eb8da78713e474ae343bea7c43276215361e98794de802d20a38989985d6f91cee339081c0fbcb509903cb63b6942665abb9e6fa0587e75cbb70392c5669cbdb375c89443ccebaf699dc209c1b82423929ce5e2de37b44df4b5cd99bc32f92aadc3d1e7836a54a48dff3e27b185e263997f7ae1c48fc82e591753dfe5fdbbbe2e77d9cf2e39c2f40c58fa75e0d71dc99621a3982034c3ef3fb4515e528aba6ba1cc20882fe67b7b620922105e9d3bc2b26a870c5f1a9980ba895e695ae664b1a57beba5cd0466ecd9f8318e5946e7692c77f79976c76651ae46402549ca2bcb1b037f4a82aa2647a7ac0ac58dd4de53f45f601b1f47ab2dea287ce02e6696f456eb304d1c4fb9586a43b0552eb15108a05d26cb01bbd7cbadd57c8d0e1fa78e0515e079&original=3f6d64353d3162643634623861376534323735613033396135343763323362383930333164267069643d312d73322e302d303032313836393337333930303234302d6d61696e2e706466).
But I do not want to use the above direction of proof. Help me get a direct proof.

Comment: FYI: the tags contain explanatory text. Be sure to check these before using them. In this case, your use of `[regular-rings]` associated the question with a different type of regular ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is VNR and let $I$ be a proper ideal.

Then $R/I$ is VNR too.

VNR rings are semiprimitive, so the zero ideal of $R/I$ is the intersection of maximal ideals of $R/I$.

By correspondence, $I$ is the intersection of maximal ideals of $R$ containing $I$.

QED